protoc failed: bundle.proto: contains proto3 optional fields #57
I am facing an issue when running cargo build in the jito-labs/searcher-examples project. The error message I receive is:
"called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Custom { kind: Other, error: protoc failed: bundle.proto: This file contains proto3 optional fields, but --experimental_allow_proto3_optional was not set."
It seems to be a problem related to the proto3 optional fields. How can I resolve this issue and set the correct flag?
Thank you for your assistance.

It looks like you got your answer on their GitHub at https://github.com/jito-labs/searcher-examples/issues/57:

try to follow compiler hint.


in jito_protos/build.rs

use tonic_build::configure;

fn main() {
    configure()
        .protoc_arg("--experimental_allow_proto3_optional")
        .compile(
            &[
                "protos/auth.proto",
                "protos/block.proto",
                "protos/block_engine.proto",
                "protos/bundle.proto",
                "protos/packet.proto",
                "protos/relayer.proto",
                "protos/searcher.proto",
                "protos/shared.proto",
            ],
            &["protos"],
        )
        .unwrap();
}


Yes, but when I ran backrun I got the error: "Unimplemented, message: 'subscribe_mempool is deprecated."

That's a different issue -- Jito disabled their mempool months ago

Yes, I read this any other way to listen? I was stuck from a week.

Not that I know of, sorry! You'll need to look for mempools on Solana, or find some other way to get user transactions, maybe through running your own RPC node that routes user orders
